# DoNotPromptForConvert Fails to Suppress popup in Excel 2010

Tags: c#, popup, excel-2010

I'm have a .Net project that is automating the transfer of information between Excel workbooks.  The code opens up an Excel 2010 application, opens up a Workbook that is in xlExcel8 format, creates a blank workbook in xlExcel8 format and transfers a page from the first workbook to the blank workbook. I have not been able to suppress the pop-up message when I save the blank workbook even though I've used the DoNotPromptForConvert command. The Code I've been using is:

```
        private static void QuickTest()
    {
        Object M = Type.Missing;

        string FullFileName2 = "C:\\Users\\Bill Corry\\Venrock\\SusansProject\\Test.xls";                //blank WkbkName
        string FullFileName = "C:\\Users\\Bill Corry\\Venrock\\SusansProject\\VRQtrCompInfoReqv8.xls";   //Template
        XLHlpr XLH = new XLHlpr();      // start a helper class 

        XL.Workbook srcWkBk = XLH.OpenExistingWorkbook(FullFileName, false);    //open WkBk with Format xlExcel8
        srcWkBk.DoNotPromptForConvert = true;                                   //try to suppress pop-up message

        XL.Workbook WkBk = XLH.GetNewWorkbook();                                //open blank workbook 
        WkBk.DoNotPromptForConvert = true;
        WkBk.SaveAs(FullFileName2, XL.XlFileFormat.xlExcel8, M, M, M, M, XL.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, M, M, M, M, M);  //no popup here
            //Copy Worksheet from first file to blank workbook
        XL.Worksheet WkSht = (XL.Worksheet)srcWkBk.Worksheets[1];           
        WkSht.Copy(WkBk.Worksheets[1], M);
        WkBk.DoNotPromptForConvert = true;
        WkBk.Save();                                  //Popup occurrs on this step
        WkBk.Close(false, M, M);
        srcWkBk.Close(M, M, M);                     
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The command I was looking for was to set WkBk.CheckCompatibility = false for the workbooks.  This suppressed the popup about possibly losing data when saving a workbook as a lower version of Excel.